# Lower RAM module design for ZX Spectrum

Tags: zx-spectrum, ram, dram

While the upper DRAM chips for the ZX Spectrum (4164) are more stable and still accessable, the lower DRAM chips (4116) will become a critical component in the future. One of the solutions to this problem is to produce a module that would replace all eight lower RAM chips at once.

There was an attempt to develop an [open design module](https://spectrumcomputing.co.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8782) with IS62C256AL-45ULI 32k SRAM, 74HCT574 latch and 74HCT04 inverter. The idea is quite simple: originally, 7-bit rows and 7-bit columns must be provided before a bit is written to or read from the DRAM; the latch is there to store the row so that both row and column addresses are transferred to the SRAM at once.

The problem is the implementation. The current design requires a four-layer PCB (two extra layers just for ground and power lines) and some time delay using a simple RC circuit. And nobody really knows *exactly* why. I
would like to simplify the design to a standard PCB with two layers.

We are not talking lightning fast speeds here (150ns access time) and the ZX Spectrum board does not have a four layer PCB either. The chips are much faster and there is no reason why there should be a problem at all.

I know a little bit about chip communication (I have bitbanged various serial and parallel communications), so I'd like to get to the bottom of the problem. But for that I would need information on how ULA works, with all the necessary timings. Also, I do not know anything about the correct design of the PCB, and that could be crucial in case of fast communication. I even suspect that the PCB design is responsible for the problems.

So, boiled down to three specific questions:

1. Shouldn't it be possible to develop a RAM module with only a two-layer PCB?
2. Where can I get ULA RAM read/write specifications for ZX Spectrums (including timings)?
3. How can I design the PCB so that there are no problems with signals?

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing.SE! Thanks for the question; I read it with great interest, since the implementation of the ZX Spectrum and its clones are of great interest to me. But this site requires a question to be way more specific and answerable. I hope you are able to pin this down to an actual question. I hope you stay and contribute more questions about the ZX Spectrum as well.

Comment: *Very* interesting link (and question), so +1. However, maybe a bit broad? But I've not voted to close. Is there a particular aspect that you are stuck with? Small tip: *not a forum* :-)

Comment: You want to take a new module and make a new but simpler module? What does that have to do with retrocomputing, even if the module could be used to replace old memory chips? Also, yes, the problem really is that new chips are much faster than old chips, they have much stronger and faster outputs. They are much more demanding ICs that require a much more from their environment where they are in to work properly.

Comment: @Greenonline My request can be boiled down to three specific questions - I edited OP.  I think that opening three separate questions might be counterproductive.

Comment: Given that your three questions are very different, they should be asked separately.  They can refer to each other to establish some cohesion.

Comment: @Pygmalion One problem at a time is what most fits at RC.SE. It also might help you to focus on what you really need to know.

Comment: Only question #2 is retrocomputing. Questions #1 and #3 are electronics questions about desigining a new PCB with new/modern components.

Comment: As Justme says, you'd be better off asking #1 and #3 on [SE.Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), again as separate questions. Leaving just #2 for this site.

Comment: Question part #1 has a simple answer: Yes. Which does not really help.

Comment: Question part #3 seems to be not well suited for any StackExchange site, because it implicitly asks for a course in PCB design.